# Enable compose metrics in android application

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to enable compose metrics by this official [docs](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md).

In root gradle I added this:

```
subprojects {
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        if (project.findProperty("composeCompilerReports") == "true") {
            kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" +
                        project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_reports"
            )
            kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                        project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

and start the building by this command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PcomposeCompilerReports=true  --rerun-tasks
```

the building starts and even one report for one application module in its build folder created. But as I understand the further process stuck with an error:

```
   > Task :core-common-feature-utils:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination

Plugin "androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin" usage:
  liveLiterals <true|false>  Enable Live Literals code generation
  liveLiteralsEnabled <true|false>
                             Enable Live Literals code generation (with per-file enabled flags)
  generateFunctionKeyMetaClasses <true|false>
                             Generate function key meta classes with annotations indicating the functions and their group keys. Generally used for tooling.
  sourceInformation <true|false>
                             Include source information in generated code
  metricsDestination <path>  Save compose build metrics to this folder
  reportsDestination <path>  Save compose build reports to this folder
  intrinsicRemember <true|false>
                             Include source information in generated code
  suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck <true|false>
                             Suppress Kotlin version compatibility check
  generateDecoys <true|false>
                             Generate decoy methods in IR transform


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

Also, I noticed that every time the process give the error with different module after one successful and can give my 2 same errors or three - and finally stackoverflow error.
please, help with idea how to overcome this

gradle plugin ver 7.4.1

P.S. As I understand from investigations, the modules without in their gradle

```
   kotlin("kapt")
id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
```

creates the report. The using of kotlin("kapt") gives that error. But I do not know how to compile the project without it, because I am using hilt.

**P.P.S. As I am trying more, I have managed to make reports after deleting hilt from build.gradle in modules. In this case the command runs till 100%. But application will not run of course. This is a little "inconvenient" to make report in such a way.
Please, if you have an idea..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the ones with the same problem: I just solved the same issue by migrating my gradle files to kts (build.gradle to build.gradle.kts) and now the compose metrics are working correctly (I use Hilt and Kapt).

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75529022/4232793)

EDIT: this is my build.gradle.kts (that's the only file, single module application):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.4.1"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.8.10"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.target33.maintest"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.target33.maintest"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        //comment following lines (freeCompilerArgs) to disable compose-metrics
        freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" + project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics")
        freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination="  + project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.4"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.1")

    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.0-alpha01")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-beta01")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.0-beta01")
    implementation("androidx.window:window:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

    //Hilt libraries
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    //Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3")

    //Splash screen
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0")

    //Immutable Collections Library for Kotlin (to make list, map, etc.. stable)
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.5")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

EDIT:

To avoid deprecation on project.buildDir.absolutePath

```
'getter for buildDir: File' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

just replace

```
project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics"
```

with

```
project.projectDir.toPath().toString() + "/build/compose_metrics"
```

Comment: As you see I used kts from the begining. But have this problem. Can you provide your gradle file with your working skript?

Comment: I edited my original post with my build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 2):

Use this way :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {

    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        //..
    }

    buildTypes {
        //..
    }

}

dependencies {
    //..
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                        project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics",
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination="+
                        project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics",
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had the build.gradle as in your snippet everything would be OK. But I have   id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    kotlin("kapt") in plugins section and the error is still here. Project will not compile until I remove this.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add it to root gradle file. You may add this code to module gradle file with compose:

```
android {
kotlinOptions {
    if (project.findProperty("enableComposeReports") == "true") {
        val outputDir = project.buildDir.path + "/compose-reports"
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=$outputDir",
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=$outputDir"
        )
    }
}
}
```

or use buildSrc scripts to prevent code duplication. See this repo for example https://github.com/olshevski/compose-navigation-reimagined/blob/main/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/compose-compiler-reports.gradle.kts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this wasn't help, I tried this first before asking the question. Also, in the repo you provided there is not hilt. Example with  kotlin("kapt") id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin") and script at the same time would help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this script in the root build.gradle, don't forget change "com.android.myapplication" by your application package. After that, you will do run this `./gradlew assembleRelease -P com.android.myapplication.enableComposeCompilerReports=true`

Option build.gradle.kts: Copy this script below plugins.
Note: If you have a imports problems check top-level file if you imported a package called `import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`
When you run this script for second time you must use   `./gradlew assembleRelease -P com.android.myapplication.enableComposeCompilerReports=true --rerun-tasks`

```
subprojects {
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        if (project.findProperty("com.android.myapplication.enableComposeCompilerReports") == "true") {
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" +
                      strong text  File(project.buildDir, "compose_metrics").absolutePath

            )
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                        File(project.buildDir, "compose_metrics").absolutePath
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}