# (Solved) Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm using Android Studio for Android development with Kotlin. I have more than 40 Android modules in the project: some of them are Java module, some of theme are android module.

```
Kotlin Version = "1.8.20"
Hilt Version = "2.45"
Compose BOM Version = "2023.01.00"
Compose Compiler Version = "1.4.3"
com.android.library = "7.4.1"
com.android.application = "7.4.1"
```

I want to run Compose Metrics Considering the following:

```
buildscript {
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}

subprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            if (project.findProperty("myapp.enableComposeCompilerReports") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics"
                ]
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_metrics"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I see an error as follows:

```
Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination

Plugin "androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin" usage:
  liveLiterals <true|false>  Enable Live Literals code generation
  liveLiteralsEnabled <true|false>
                             Enable Live Literals code generation (with per-file enabled flags)
  generateFunctionKeyMetaClasses <true|false>
                             Generate function key meta classes with annotations indicating the functions and their group keys. Generally used for tooling.
  sourceInformation <true|false>
                             Include source information in generated code
  metricsDestination <path>  Save compose build metrics to this folder
  reportsDestination <path>  Save compose build reports to this folder
  intrinsicRemember <true|false>
                             Include source information in generated code
  suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck <true|false>
                             Suppress Kotlin version compatibility check
  generateDecoys <true|false>
                             Generate decoy methods in IR transform
```

In another simple project this problem came when I added Hilt

**Update:**

If you add the kapt plugin you'll run into this issue.

Add `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.8.10' apply false` to the top-level build.gradle
Add `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'` to the app's build.gradle

Run `./gradlew assembleDebug -Pmyapp.enableComposeCompilerReports=true`

And the issue will reproduce without any Hilt dependencies added.

**Update:**

If you migrate your gradle files to kts and (use version catalog and plugin convention). I think your problem will be solved

Comment: Seems like a known issue, it has been fixed in 1.8.20-RC of kapt but for me (I need jetpack compose compiler) 1.8.20-RC of kotlin has got no compose support yet: [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55452)

Comment: If you migrate your gradle files to kts and use version catalog and plugin convention. I think your problem will be solved

Comment: Unfortunately I use Hilt, which currently uses KAPT for annotation processing and doesn't support KSP yet

Comment: it doesn't matter. i suggest to try it out

Comment: You are right! I've converted my build.gradle into build.gradle.kts and now the metrics are working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: So it's time to vote my question 